# How can I detect if another process is elevated?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, process

I am running as a non-elevated process. I need to know if some other process is elevated by its process ID. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Why would you need to know that?

Comment: The proposed duplicate detects the status of the *current* process, the OP wants to detect the status of *another* process.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: However, some of the answers to that question could probably be *modified* to answer this one.  Basically, wherever GetCurrentProcess() appears, substitute OpenProcess().  (And if you get access denied, the target process is probably elevated.  Or belongs to another user.)

Comment: That's the thing - the other process is neither belongs to another user nor is it elevated. It is just a plain process like notepad.